# Error with login Twitter Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, twitter

I add my application login by Twitter by add all data for documentation. But when compile my project and press log in Twitter next go to load data but next go to load to activity from login screen :)

This is my activity witch login by Twitter

```
@BindView(R.id.signInTwitterButton)
TwitterLoginButton signInTwitterButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(getString(R.string.twitter_api), getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_secret));

    TwitterConfig twitterConfig = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
            .twitterAuthConfig(authConfig)
            .build();

    Twitter.initialize(twitterConfig);

    signInTwitterButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            handleTwitterSession(result.data);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Error " + exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}


private void handleTwitterSession(TwitterSession session) {
    AuthCredential credential = TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(
            session.getAuthToken().token,
            session.getAuthToken().secret);

    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        goMainScreen();
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    signInTwitterButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

This is my error log

```
09-21 18:20:50.538 10055-10055/magdalena.pl.dreamguide E/Twitter: Failed to get request token
  com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: HTTP request failed, Status: 400
    at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onResponse(Callback.java:42)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

09-21 18:20:50.568 10055-10055/magdalena.pl.dreamguide E/Twitter: Authorization completed with an error
  com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Failed to get request token
    at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthController$1.failure(OAuthController.java:94)
    at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth1aService$1.failure(OAuth1aService.java:191)
    at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onResponse(Callback.java:42)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: The HTTP 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server could not understand the request due to invalid syntax. The client should not repeat this request without modification.  There is something wrong with your token and secret.

Comment: I check my key are  good:)